# Is there any way by which we can see query running for stream/ table in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-platform

I want to see the query running for my stream/table in Kafka.

```
Create stream foo as select * from bar where distuinguisher='xxx';

 Message                    
----------------------------
 Stream created and running 
----------------------------
```

Once somebody created stream/table I can only query the stream/table. Is there any way through which I can see the logic or complete query behind the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DESCRIBE EXTENDED` will give you this information. You can also use `SHOW QUERIES` to see all queries that are running.

For example:

```sql
ksql> DESCRIBE EXTENDED FOO;

Name                 : FOO
Type                 : STREAM
Key field            :
Key format           : STRING
Timestamp field      : Not set - using <ROWTIME>
Value format         : JSON
Kafka topic          : FOO (partitions: 1, replication: 1)

 Field   | Type
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ROWTIME | BIGINT           (system)
 ROWKEY  | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)
 LOGGER  | VARCHAR(STRING)
 LEVEL   | VARCHAR(STRING)
 TIME    | BIGINT
 MESSAGE | STRUCT<TYPE INTEGER, DESERIALIZATIONERROR STRUCT<ERRORMESSAGE VARCHAR(STRING), RECORDB64 VARCHAR(STRING), CAUSE ARRAY<VARCHAR(STRING)>>, RECORDPROCESSINGERROR STRUCT<ERRORMESSAGE VARCHAR(STRING), RECORD VARCHAR(STRING), CAUSE ARRAY<VARCHAR(STRING)>>, PRODUCTIONERROR STRUCT<ERRORMESSAGE VARCHAR(STRING)>>
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Queries that write from this STREAM
-----------------------------------
CSAS_FOO_1 : CREATE STREAM FOO WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='FOO', PARTITIONS=1, REPLICAS=1) AS SELECT *
FROM KSQL_PROCESSING_LOG KSQL_PROCESSING_LOG
EMIT CHANGES;

For query topology and execution plan please run: EXPLAIN <QueryId>

Local runtime statistics
------------------------


(Statistics of the local KSQL server interaction with the Kafka topic FOO)
ksql>
```

```sql
ksql> SHOW QUERIES;

 Query ID   | Kafka Topic | Query String
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CSAS_FOO_1 | FOO         | CREATE STREAM FOO WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='FOO', PARTITIONS=1, REPLICAS=1) AS SELECT *
FROM KSQL_PROCESSING_LOG KSQL_PROCESSING_LOG
EMIT CHANGES;
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
For detailed information on a Query run: EXPLAIN <Query ID>;
ksql>
```